# FB.login() popup blocked only in mobile web application

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

For our mobile web application using the Facebook Javascript SDK, we want to check the user's login status, and then display the Facebook login dialog if necessary.  The following code is run within a click handler for a given button in our web app:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // do something with the logged in and authorized user
        } else if (response.status === 'not authorized') {
            // logged in but has not authorized our app
        } else {
            // not logged in
            FB.login();
        }
    });
});
```

Ensuring that the user is not logged into Facebook, this works fine and displays the login dialog for desktop web browsers when the button is pressed, but not for the mobile web (at least not for Android on a variety of browsers, I don't have access to an iPhone currently).  Nothing appears on the mobile web app, and when I disable the popup blocker, then I get a prompt asking if I want to allow this popup, which works.

Does anyone know why the behavior is different and/or what the known/standard workarounds are?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code will **not** work in all desktop browsers. Some browsers (mobile and desktop) block popups *unless* they are initiated by a user click. For example,

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
   FB.login();
});
```

will work because the `FB.login()` function is *only* being called in response to the user's click. So to fix your code, replace the `FB.login()` call with some code that displays a 'login' button and text encouraging the user to click that button.

Comment: Hi Gil, thanks for your response.  I am updating the code as I forgot to specify the code is being called in response to a user's click.  How does this affect the popup blocking if the user click triggers an AJAX call (FB.getLoginStatus) whose response triggers the actual popup (FB.login)?

Comment: What I said still applies. Since you are calling `FB.login()` from a *callback* function the browser considers that to be apart from the user's *click* action.

Comment: Gotcha. We're trying to avoid having the user click another button if possible, so I'll explore another way of improving this flow.

Comment: call getLoginStatus() on page load so that when the user clicks the button you already know the status.

Comment: Haha I just made that change, thanks!  What if I wanted to do something else, like launch a FB dialog upon a user clicking one of many buttons but had to first make an AJAX call to retrieve the dynamic (based on which button they pressed) message text?

Comment: Get all the Ajax content on page load ;) Seriously though, making the user click twice isn't necessarily a bad thing. I'm sure there are cases where if you warn the user that an authorization dialog is coming before actually showing it, they will be more inclined to click it than when you shove it in their face without warning. A lot of people have been conditioned to hate pop-ups. I think Facebook is changing that, but there's still a stigma.